# how to test a setting in vue.config.js from src\main.ts?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, configuration, vue-cli

I'm modifying my vue app to add code to force redirect from http to https, when you navigate to  the page.

(Yes know doing it in the webserver is better, belt & suspenders)

```
if (location.protocol !== 'https:') {
  console.info('redirecting!')
  location.replace(`https:${location.href.substring(location.protocol.length)}`)
} else {
  console.info('not redirecting...')
}
```

but I want to skip that code if in vue.config.js

```
  devServer: {
    https: true,
```

if that setting is changed to false.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't do this, the app is totally unaware of what happens in vue.config.js, the only thing you could try is to use some environment flag var that is responsible for both places. Any way, dev server isn't supposed to be used in prod

Comment: In prod it's hosted in IIS, I just want to be able to turn it all off easily in dev, and not worry about doing it manually.

Comment: Then that's it, use env var like VUE_ENABLE_HTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue compiled application cannot be aware of the contents of vue.config.js, and vice versa. Both parts can depend on common environment variable with `VUE_` prefix which can be provided from .env file or elsewhere:

```
  devServer: {
    https: process.env.VUE_HTTPS === '1',
    ...
```

and

```
if (process.env.VUE_HTTPS === '1' && location.protocol !== 'https:') {
  ...
```